# Oracle referential integrity against data range in PK table

Tags: constraints, referential-integrity, oracle12c

Consider the following design:

```
LEGAL_CASE table (columns)
--------------------------------
LEGAL_CASE_ID
APPELLATE_CRT_ID
DISTRICT_CRT_ID
TRIAL_CRT_ID
```

with all courts being defined in a lookup table

```
COURT table (data)
--------------------------------------------
CRT_ID     CRT_TYPE      CRT_NAME
--------------------------------------------
1          A             APPELLATE COURT 1
2          A             APPELLATE COURT 2
3          D             DISTRICT COURT 1
4          D             DISTRICT COURT 2
5          T             TRIAL COURT 1
6          T             TRIAL COURT 2
```

The standard way of doing it, I suppose, would be to have a separate lookup table for each court type but I prefer dumping them all in a single one under different codes, for compactness and elegance.  So then I would like to have some form of referential integrity constraint (if the above rules out FK) that will enforce that all it can go into APPELLATE_CRT_ID are the CRT_ID values from the COURT table **but only where CRT_TYPE = 'A'** etc.  A regular FK would allow Ds and Ts as well but I would like to make it more restrictive.

Is there a way to formulate a FK that would restrict a range of values in the primary key table or should I just go with a `RULE` or another type of `CONSTRAINT`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want referential integrity given that lookup table, you'd need to add multiple `CRT_TYPE` columns to the `legal_case` table and include those as part of the foreign key.  Something like

```
CREATE TABLE legal_case (
  legal_case_id      integer primary key,
  appellate_crt_id   integer,
  appellate_crt_type varchar2(1),
  district_crt_id    integer,
  district_crt_type  varchar2(1),
  ...
  constraint fk_appelate_crt foreign key (appelate_crt_id, appellate_crt_type) references court(crt_id, crt_type),
  constraint fk_district_crt foreign key (district_crt_id, district_crt_type)  references court(crt_id, crt_type),
  ...
);
```

Of course, this would require that the primary key (or a unique constraint though I dislike foreign keys that reference nno-primary keys) of the `court` table would be `crt_id, crt_type` rather than just `crt_id`.

Otherwise, you'd be looking at writing triggers to verify this sort of thing (which gets rather painful if you want to prevent session A from modifying a `court` row while session B has uncommitted changes that depend on the existing state of that row) or possibly creating an `on commit` materialized view with an appropriate set of constraints that combined the data from these two tables.

Comment: `appellate_crt_type` would always be the same value in `legal_case`.  that's redundant.  I don't like that.  Can I have a rule that defines the acceptable range of values in `appellate_crt_id` as `SELECT CRT_ID FROM COURT WHERE CRT_TYPE = 'A'`?

Comment: @amphibient - Yes, it's redundant.  But that's the only way to get referential integrity given how you want to structure the `court` table.  That's why I'd prefer different lookup tables for each court type in this case.  No, you can't create a constraint that validates data in one table based on a query against some other table.